# Ubuntu raid not showing on windows 7

Tags: installation, raid

I have windows 7 recently installed on single disk and would like to install games on the slave drives to act faster its a small raid of 2 160gb disks, thing is i have also Ubuntu installed there with hours worth of dl's  and would like to keep it, the drive is not usable in windows though i can see it as a blank drive though the device manager, something about the MBR most probably, if i create a partition will i lose the Ubuntu data?

Comment: What you are facing is a Windows problem and not an Ubuntu problem. Microsoft refuses to acknowledge ext filesystems. Nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you are saying windows recognizes the raid array, or the individual drives that make it up.  If it is a Linux software raid, then Windows won't recognize the array, only the individual drives.  In this case, there's nothing you can do.  If it is a fakeraid, then Windows will recognize the array, but not the filesystem in it, as Curious Apprentice said.

Comment: my array has ubuntu and i want to protect it if i format for ntfs use along with win 7, my guess is i have to create a new partition in ubuntu that i can use readily in windows?

Comment: @mark, assuming it is a fakeraid that Windows can see, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to open Ext4 linux partitions from Windows, then it wont work. Windows does not recognize ext4 file system, therefore it will show them as empty and as Primary ones.

If you want to read data from those partitions then install "Linux Reader" on Windows.
http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

Comment: thanks im new on ubuntu use it rarely and appreciate the help